# Data noise with PCA

Tags: matlab, gaussian, pca

I have a question related to data noise and principle component analysis (PCA).

**Situation**

I have a data matrix containing X, Y, Z joint data. I have applied PCA, with the stipulation of retaining 98% of the variance.  However, even after reduction the data still remains very noise.

**Problem**

I have spent a few hours reading and I'm unsure of the best approach to take. I need to perform PCA for dimension reduction, however the noise present in the dataset still presents several issues. I need an intermediate step before applying PCA to reduce the noise contained in the dataset. I have been advised that Gaussian Smoothing might be the best way forward before applying PCA.

Can anyone suggest the best approach to take?

**Edit**
Apologise for not being clear in my question.

[Original data](http://www.speedyshare.com/gX4Dd/O.mat): Here is an example of the original data. [Projected](http://www.speedyshare.com/8DCAJ/P.mat): with 98% of the variance retained.

[image: PCA performed on matrix in the first 3 dimensions]

There is still a little noise in the projection. At least 4 points are not uniform in there positioning.

Comment: how can 300-by-90 by X Y Z data? how many points you have and in what dimension? what type of noise do you have? how do you plan to smooth the data? you must provide more information...

Comment: Not sure that posting links to files for downloading is going to lead to your question being re-opened.

Comment: I was attempting to assist in improving my question. Have you got any suggestions how I can provide the sample data?

Comment: @Dan do you mean you have 4 points that are "outliers" - outside the "spiral" where the rest of the point reside?

Comment: @Shai that's correct. This example isn't as bad as others - I'd like denoise the data to lead to a uniform spiral.

Comment: @Dan then I think my answer provides a good pointer on "robust PCA". I beleive there's matlab code available in the link I posted.